# Forcing a .Net IMAP service to quit

Tags: .net, outlook, exchange-server

I've written an application that uses Outlook and Redemption to do some syncing operations with Exchange server over IMAP. It works great until it tries to exit. It executes the very last line of code, which is print "Service exiting" just fine, but this line occurs *after* the Application.Quit() call I make on Outlook. And the Outlook 2010 icon is still sitting in the task bar!

My question is: How can I force Outlook to close (even in a quick and dirty way) so that my application is guaranteed to quit, without hanging there waiting for Outlook to finish closing, which sometimes it just never does? (It waits for a user to right click the task bar icon and select 'Exit' instead)

TIA
Dave
--Trindaz on Fedang #Exchange-integration

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Redemption, but it seems to be some tool that helps Automate Outlook in some way, and whenever you automate any Office application you always have to be careful to clear everything properly, otherwise it will be left with a hanging reference and might not shut down properly.

So, unless your usage of Redemption changes things in some way, I'd suggest that you might need to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on any references to anything in Outlook that you use.

To be able to do that you have to be careful that you always store all the references that you access somewhere, so avoid doing nested calls like:

```
SomeOutlookObject.SomeInnerOutLookObject.SomeMethod
```

And instead do

```
Object innerObj = SomeOutlookObject.SomeInnerOutLookObject;
innerObj.SomeMethod
```

That way you can call `ReleaseComObject` on the `innerObj` as well.